# shutdown a master server with a python script

Tags: python, database, server

I have a question about shutting down a server.

I have two servers A and B. I want a script that shuts one server down. For instance, server A has to run the script while server B is down or rebooted. Can somebody help me with this question?

Answer (score 1):

scripting a shutdown and/or reboot script would be reinventing the wheel you could use already published source codes that can do more than that what you're looking for is [remote administration tool](https://github.com/topics/remote-admin-tool?l=python)